# property not found of object of type 'segmentControl' iphone

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I have defined segmentControl buttons.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) SegmentControl *option;
SegmentControl *result = [[SegmentControl alloc] initWithFrame:frame items:@[@"Bad", @"Good"]];


result:self.option.selectedSegmentIndex
```

why am I getting this error: property 'selectedSegmentIndex' not found on object of type 'segmentControl',

```
@class SegmentControl;
@protocol SegmentControlDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)segmentControl:(SegmentControl *)segmentControl didSelectSegment:(UIButton *)segment;

@end

@interface SegmentControl : UIView

@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL staySelected;
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<SegmentControlDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame items:(NSArray *)items;

@end
```

Comment: Because the "SegmentControl" class doesn't have a property named "selectedSegmentIndex", perhaps?

Comment: yes, what should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by "what you should use"?

Comment: how can I access the selected segmentControl Button?

Comment: Well, would you please show how the `SegmentControl` class is declared? I cannot possibly have a clue without seeing the relevant part of the code.

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: Yes, exactly as I thought - you don't declare a property named `selectedSegmentIndex`. Why do you expect it to be there?

Comment: what property I can use based on SegmentControl class defined here?

Comment: I don't know what your intention is, but you have to declare and define a property if you want to use it. That's all I can say.

Comment: Could it be that you actually wanted to use the stock `UISegmentedControl` but do not know how to use it?

Comment: it was defined as SegmentControl,I was just wondering based on the defined class how I can access its property.

Answer (score 0):

Your class SegmentControl needs to be a subclass of UISegmentControl (not UIView).